# Simple redirect to previous page doesn't work php

Tags: php

I have page `drops.php` and button on this page `addDrops.php?group_id=6`. Now I'm trying when I go to `addDrops.php` and after I add new value to redirect me back `addDrops.php?group_id=6`. I've made it like this

```
if ( !empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['add'] )) 
{           
    $field_name = $_POST['field_name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO form_fields ( field_name, group_id ) VALUE ( ?, ? )";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($field_name, $group_id));

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field_name">Name:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input type="username" class="form-control" name="field_name" id="field_name">

            </div>
    </div>                  
    <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Dropdown option" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So simple form with one field and I added this for redirection but after form submit it doesn't redirect

> header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, also, temporary remove the header and do a `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])` what does it return ?

Comment: Is `}
<form` in your actual page, or are those separate pages?

Comment: @JDR Im pretty sure the default action is the PHP_SELF, so that would be redundant.

Comment: @PedroLobito there is no errors. The script is working fine and is adding everything into database. Just doesn't redirect. chris85 they are on same page. This is just snipped.

Comment: And var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) return the current url  `addDrops.php?group_id=14` - It should return `drops.php?group_id=14` because this is prevous url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you posted in your comments, you don't need to use the referer, you have to hardcode the URL `drops.php` and append the group id.

The referer is the page from which you post comes from, and in this case, it's not  the same page that you want to go back.

```php
header('Location: drops.php?group_id=' . $group_id);
```

Comment: Ah i didn't think in this way and of course this is work perfectly. Thank's very much!